# Google Directions API - Route is blurred after a new request

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

[here is a picture with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp6vv.jpg).

I am using Vue.js to consume a REST API that send data about upcoming bus transfers. In the picture above each list item represents a transfer and when clicked, the map should show the route. **When switching from smaller to bigger is okay, but then when I switch to a shorter route, the blue line indicating it appears blurred and bigger than normal**. The problem disappears when I zoom in/out, it's just the initial display.

I've tried the *setZoom(int)* function on the map object after every new request, but that didn't work.

**Here's the relevant code from the Vue instance:**

```
methods: {
     ...
        calcRoute() {
          const request = {
            origin: this.start,
            destination: this.end
          }

          this.directionsService.route(request, (result, status) => {
            if (status == 'OK') {
              this.directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
               //this.map.setZoom(12);
            }
          })
        }
},
watch: {
      start: () => {
        if (this.end && this.start) {
          this.calcRoute();
        }
      },
       ...
    }
```

**EDIT: as suggested, I've provided a running code snippet. Click the CHANGE DIRECTIONS button to see the problem.**

**EDIT 2: I've implemented it in pure JS for simplicity**

**EDIT 3: Provide your API KEY**

```js
const transfers = [{
  "id": 29,
  "date": "2020-02-12T08:00:00.000Z",
  "pick_up": "Sofia Airport, Terminal 1",
  "drop_off": "Stara Zagora",
  "driver": "СТ",
  "vehicle": 6264,
},
{
  "id": 43,
  "date": "2020-02-13T08:30:00.000Z",
  "pick_up": "Sofia Terminal 1",
  "drop_off": "Boutique One Hotel Sofia",
  "driver": "СТ",
  "vehicle": 6264,
}];

let map, directionsService, directionsRenderer;
let selectedTrans = 0;

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {
      lat: 42.698334,
      lng: 23.319941
    }
  });
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  calcRoute();
});

function calcRoute() {
  const start = transfers[selectedTrans].pick_up;
  const end= transfers[selectedTrans].drop_off;
  const request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  };

  directionsService.route(request, (result, status) => {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
    }
  })
}

document.getElementById('changeDirectionsBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  selectedTrans = selectedTrans == 0 ? 1 : 0;
  calcRoute();
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="changeDirectionsBtn"> Change Directions </button>
<div id="map">
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY" defer></script>
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue, not just 2 methods that show basic implementation of the API. Please take the [tour] and read on [ask].

Comment: @MrUpsidown Thank you for the provided feedback. I've edited my question. Hope you can help now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd need to investigate this a bit further when I have some time...

The documentation mentions that

> *Because the renderer is an MVCObject, it will automatically detect any changes to its properties and update the map when its associated directions have changed.*

and I am not sure about what that exactly means.

That said, simply calling `directionsRenderer.setMap(null);` before calculating the new route and `directionsRenderer.setMap(map);` in the callback fixes the issue. See the snippet below.

```js
const transfers = [{
  "id": 29,
  "date": "2020-02-12T08:00:00.000Z",
  "pick_up": "Sofia Airport, Terminal 1",
  "drop_off": "Stara Zagora",
  "driver": "СТ",
  "vehicle": 6264,
},
{
  "id": 43,
  "date": "2020-02-13T08:30:00.000Z",
  "pick_up": "Sofia Terminal 1",
  "drop_off": "Boutique One Hotel Sofia",
  "driver": "СТ",
  "vehicle": 6264,
}];

let map, directionsService, directionsRenderer;
let selectedTrans = 0;

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {
      lat: 42.698334,
      lng: 23.319941
    }
  });
  
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  
  calcRoute();
});

function calcRoute() {

  directionsRenderer.setMap(null);

  const start = transfers[selectedTrans].pick_up;
  const end= transfers[selectedTrans].drop_off;
  const request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  };

  directionsService.route(request, (result, status) => {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
      directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
    }
  })
}

document.getElementById('changeDirectionsBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  selectedTrans = selectedTrans == 0 ? 1 : 0;
  calcRoute();
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="changeDirectionsBtn"> Change Directions </button>
<div id="map">
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" defer></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixes the issue but I think it's still a bug on the Google's side :D

Comment: Feel free to report it in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188853%20status:open).